# Help understanding why no significance after p-value adjustment

Tags: multiple-regression, p-value, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I performed multiple regression on 40 response variables against 6 predictors for 30 samples. Below are the raw and FDR adjusted p-values for the key variable in the study.

I'm confused as to why my raw pvalues have quite a few that are significant and near significant, but my adjusted pvalues are all basically equal to 1.

```
#######  RAW P-VALUES  ######
> all_ici_score_regression_stats$pvals$CaseStringAMD %>% sort()
 [1] 0.02735845 0.04656392 0.06916870 0.08117567 0.09310255 0.16371951 0.16515110 0.16868411
 [9] 0.17054889 0.21126655 0.21835158 0.22002100 0.22256004 0.23715104 0.29166627 0.30556770
[17] 0.33038564 0.33946461 0.35223124 0.35870318 0.36828037 0.39522214 0.41585669 0.43741361
[25] 0.43932712 0.45852017 0.51128991 0.51804470 0.52444482 0.54991299 0.62044742 0.62628386
[33] 0.74017094 0.74316886 0.78275662 0.91185935 0.96564077 0.97913020 0.98580017 0.99016260

#######  BH ADJUSTED P-VALUES  ######
> all_ici_score_regression_stats$pvals$CaseStringAMD.adj %>% p.adjust(method='BH')
 [1] 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626
[10] 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626
[19] 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626
[28] 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626
[37] 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626 0.9901626
```

When I plot the sorted pvalues and bin them, I feel like there is a reasonable trend towards significance. But the adjusted pvals are basically equal to 1.

[image]

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here? This is fairly dirty human data, so I'm pretty ok with significance at the 0.1 level.

Comment: Isn't this the whole point of FDR adjustment?  Incidentally, what are you focusing on where you see a "reasonable trend towards significance" and what are you comparing it to?

Comment: Well, I'll be completely subjective here...There are a number of raw pvalues close to 1, and then slopes down rapidly. At least a quarter of them are below 0.2. Linguistically "adjusting" does not equate to throwing them all out entirely. Also, the complete rejection of all pvalues for this variable as well as others simply makes no sense in our biological system. We know from other ways of looking at the data, as well as multiple publications that we should see good significance for at least some features, and even moreso for demographic variables such as age and gender. So...?

Comment: Your histogram of p-values looks almost uniform, which is what you would expect to see if all your nulls were true. Once you adjust for multiple testing, there's not much to see.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample is tiny. In a single study, I wouldn't expect to find any significance at all unless the true effect was huge (and even then the effect would be estimated with little precision). If you set your significance level to be .1, then if there were no true effects in the data, you would expected to see significant findings 10% of the time. Indeed, you found 5/40 significant findings, or 12.5%, which is almost exactly as many as you'd expect to find if there were no true effects. The probability of finding a significant effect in at least one of the studies would be almost .99, even if there were no true effects. The p-value adjustment adjusts your p-values to account for this fact so that the probability of finding a significant effect in at least one of the studies is the nominal level (in your case, .1). After this adjustment, it's clear that your results are entirely consistent with there being no effects. This isn't a problem with the theory; you have bad (small) data.